# How can I use a variable inside OPENQUERY

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, openquery

I am getting an error running the code below. I believe it as to do with the number of single quotes used. 
How can I set a variable inside OPENQUERY command?

```
@declare @myStr varchar(6)
set @myStr = 'Test1'

SELECT *    
FROM OPENQUERY("192.168.1.1",'SET FMTONLY OFF; EXEC spNewTest @Param1 = ''+ @myStr +''')
```

[Click to see the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jcra.png)

Regards,
Elio Fernandes

Comment: It would be helpful to add your error message

Comment: See the error message in my post.

Comment: @ElioFernandes, according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188427.aspx, the query string cannot contain variables.  You'll need to build the entire `SELECT...OPENQUERY` statement and execute the statement string with `EXECUTE` or `sp_executesql`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the answer for my question, so I thought sharing it with you.

```
DECLARE @QUERY VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @TSQL VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @SP VARCHAR(50)

DECLARE @PARAMETERS VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @PARAM1 VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @PARAM2 VARCHAR(50)

SET @TSQL = N'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([192.168.1.1], ''SET FMTONLY OFF; '
SET @SP   = 'EXEC spNewTest '

SET @PARAM1 = '@Type='''+ QUOTENAME('Test','''') + ''''
SET @PARAM2 = '@Year='''+ QUOTENAME('2016','''') + ''''
SET @PARAMETERS = @PARAM1 + ', ' + @PARAM2

SET @QUERY = @TSQL + @SP + @PARAMETERS + ''')'

EXECUTE (@QUERY)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a single quote within a string you have to put in two single quotes. For example:
'''this is a string''' would be a string containing the following:
'this is a string'

So for your problem, you have to change your code to this:

```
@declare @myStr varchar(6)
set @myStr = 'Test1'

SELECT *    
FROM OPENQUERY("192.168.1.1",'SET FMTONLY OFF; EXEC spNewTest @Param1 = '''+ @myStr +'''')
```